# The constructor Intent(FragmentTab1, Class<AlgbraHome>) is undefined

Tags: java, android

i'm working on a app that has swipe tabs inside the tabs there is buttons so for example fragmenttab1 has Algabra button i want it when the user clicks this button it takes them to 
AlgabraHome.class

AlgabraHome.class

```
package com.androidbegin.absviewpagertutorial;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;



public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

    private Button btn;
    private Button btn2;
    private Button btn3;
    private Button btn4;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.algabra);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab1.this, AlgbraHome.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }




        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }

}
```

I keep getting the flowing errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  FragmentTab1.java   
/School Tools/src/com/androidbegin/absviewpagertutorial line 35 Java Problem
The constructor Intent(FragmentTab1, Class<AlgbraHome>) is undefined    FragmentTab1.java   
/School Tools/src/com/androidbegin/absviewpagertutorial line 32 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation   FragmentTab1.java   /School Tools/src/com/androidbegin/absviewpagertutorial line 35 Java Problem
```

ive tried goggling it and no luck

please help if you can

Thanks way in advance

Regards
Rapsong11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab1.this, AlgbraHome.class);`

to

`Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab1.this.getActivity(), AlgbraHome.class);`

Answer (score 0):

The `Intent` constructor you seem to be using is

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

as seen in the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29).

The `Fragment` class is not a subclass of `Context`. If an `Activity` is currently associated with the `Fragment`, you can call `getActivity()` on the reference returned by `Fragment.this`, if that is your requirement.